# Python - Passing arguments to functions

Tags: python, function

I am sort of new to Python so I was reading through Pro Python and it had this section about passing variable keyword arguments to function. After reading that section I wrote the following code which doesn't seem to work.

```
def fun(**a):
    return a['height'] if a is not {} else 0
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: def fun(**a):     return a['height'] if a is not {} else 0

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

Empty hash from the argument is not guaranteed to be the same object as a newly created empty hash.

Try to compare using `a != {}`, or just `a['height'] if a else 0`.

Or even without the check:

```
return a.get('height', 0)
```

Comment: The get is a great suggestion. After all, {'spam': 3} isn't equal to {} or falsey, but it still doesn't have his key...